# Relocate bookmarks.xml file to maintain Sourcetree bookmarks throughout several machines (Windows)

Tags: versioning, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a Sourcetree configuration file somewhere in "C:\Users\User123\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree" where I could configure the path where the file "bookmarks.xml" is created and managed? (Windows OS)

Currently my "bookmarks.xml" is located here : "C:\Users\User123\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml". I would like it to be moved somewhere else i.e "S:\Share\NewLocationOfBookmarksFile\bookmarks.xml".

I would like to relocate "bookmarks.xml" to a shared location of my choice so that changes (for example, addition of new repos) will reflect automatically on every machines.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks